# Retrofit 2.2.0 Get specific fields from response instead of binding to an object

Tags: android, retrofit2

On android client I am using retrofit for the HTTP requests, I am having trouble with the GET method; how can I take specific field of the user, for example, I want to store the username into a variable `name = response.getUserName();` The interface always return null for some reason

```
 //This the API GET
@GET("api/user")
Call<List<Users>> listUsers();

//This is the restClient
/**
 * Getting all the users from the
 * REST API and mongoDB
 * @return
 */
public List<Users> getUsers(){
    Call<List<Users>> userList = service.listUsers();
    userList.enqueue(new Callback<List<Users>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Users>> call, Response<List<Users>> response) {

            /**
             * The is isSuccessful method find out
             * if the status code is in the range 200-300,
             * indicating success.
             */
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                users = response.body();                     
                callback.resultReady(users);
            }
        }

//Here is the callbackInterface
public interface ResulReadyCallBack {
public void resultReady(List<Users> users);
```

}

Comment: What does this mean? "The interface always return now for some reason"

Comment: Its typo I mean that the interface return null for some reason!
callback.resultReady(users); => the callback is null.